# How to autopopulate Sharepoint list with Power Automate?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, microsoft-power-automate-desktop, microsoft-flow

Im trying to autopopulate a Sharepoint list with names of the employeey with Power automate. The names of employees I want to retrieve from Office 365 Users.

I already created a flow for this but it doesnt update my list with names:

[image: Flow]

[image: Flow 2]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Flow description for the answer]

I did not try exactly what you have specified. For quick work, I used manual trigger, instead of recurrence, and OneDrive as my data source, though I imagine it should be fairly simple to translate to SharePoint.

Explanation:

Instead of listing Office 365 Users, I looked up a group of the office staff members. This was done using the "Office 365 Groups" helper.

The next thing was to create an Excel sheet on OneDrive and a table within it.
The flow references the table, and puts any field from the "List group members" action into the excel sheet in the specified column for each user.

Comment: If this answer is useful please accept it.